# AVAudioPlayer play returns false on hardware

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to write some very simple code to play an audio file.  The code works fine on the iPad2 simulator.  On my iPad2 device however, [audooPlayer play] returns false and no audio is to be heard.

I've tried both a .caf and .wav file.  I've rebooted my iPad2 and made sure the mute switch is off.  Any tips on how to debug are *greatly* appreciated.

Sample code:

```
- (void)playAudio {
    NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"wav"];
    url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:file];
    NSError *error = nil;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error creating audio player: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }
    [audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
    if (![audioPlayer prepareToPlay]) {
        NSLog(@"Error preparing audio");
        return;
    }
    // Everything works fine up to this point
    if (![audioPlayer play]) {
        // I hit this on hardware.  Works perfect on the simulator.
        NSLog(@"Error playing audio");
        return;
    }
```

Comment: I've test your code both on iPhone simulator and iPhone device(both are iOS 6.0) and it works fine! I don't have a iPad device. What's your error? Have your `audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur` been called?

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Your results helped me realize the problem was elsewhere - see my answer below.

Comment: i have  test your code both on iPhone simulator  it works fine!
but not working in real device. :((

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After way too much debugging, I finally found the culprit.  I was following the guide at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2, and earlier in my app before playing audio, I record some audio.  Based on that guide I was calling

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: NO error: nil];
```

when done recording.  This apparently causes AVAudioPlayer to fail playing audio.  Changing the call to

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];
```

instead fixes things.  It is very odd that this isn't a problem in the simulator, but causes issues on hardware.